# Farthest element within limited distance for a sorted vector

Tags: r, vector

We have a sorted vector `foo`, for each element `i` we want to find the largest `j` such that `foo[j]-foo[i] < 10`. For instance when

```
foo <- c(1,2,5,7,13,17,25,33,85)
```

the answer is:

```
bar <- c(4,4,5,5,6,7,8,8,9)
```

(for `i=1`, the largest `j` is 4 since `foo[4]-foo[1]=7-1<10`. Hence the first item of `bar` is 4).

We can easily compute `bar` using a `for` and `while` loop. But I am looking for an efficient code in R. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want something fast and memory efficient, you should simply translate your `for` and `while` loops to Rcpp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated solution using non-equi joins:**

Recently, *non-equi* joins were implemented in the [current development version of data.table, v1.9.7](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). This is quite straightforward with this feature:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
dt1 = data.table(x=foo)
dt2 = data.table(y=foo+10L)
dt1[dt2, on=.(x < y), mult="last", which=TRUE]
# [1] 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9
```

On 100,000 elements, this is faster than `foverlaps`:

```
set.seed(45L)
foo <- sort(sample(1e6, 1e5, FALSE))
dt1 = data.table(x=foo)
dt2 = data.table(y=foo+10L)
system.time(ans <- dt1[dt2, on=.(x < y), mult="last", which=TRUE])
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.011   0.001   0.011
```

Note that this operation can be done directly as follows:

```
ans <- data.table(x=foo)[.(y=x+10L), on=.(x < y), mult="last", which=TRUE]
```

---

**Old approach using `foverlaps`:**

Here's a method that would probably scale better. Using overlapping range joins function `foverlaps()` from `data.table` version 1.9.4:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.4+
x = data.table(start=foo, end=foo+9L)
lookup = data.table(start=foo, end=foo)
setkey(lookup) ## order doesn't change, as 'foo' is already sorted
foverlaps(x, lookup, mult="last", which=TRUE)
# [1] 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9
```

Timing on 100,000 numbers:

```
set.seed(45L)
foo <- sort(sample(1e6, 1e5, FALSE))
arun <- function(foo) {
    x = data.table(start=foo, end=foo+9L)
    lookup = data.table(start=foo, end=foo)
    setkey(lookup)
    foverlaps(x, lookup, mult="last", which=TRUE)
}
system.time(arun(foo))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  0.142   0.009   0.153
```

Comment: While the other solutions work, this method is faster

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 sapply(foo, function(x) {m1 <-foo-x; which.max(m1[m1<10])})
 #[1] 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no `NA` values:

```
apply(as.matrix(dist(foo)), 1, function(x) {
  which.max(cumsum(x < 10))  
  })
#1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
#4 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9
```

And here is a solution using only sparse matrices:

```
library(spam)
res <- apply.spam(as.spam(dist(foo)), 2, function(x) {
  test <- cumsum(x < 10)
  if (sum(test) > 0 ) which.max(test) else (0)
  }) + seq_along(foo)
res[length(res)] <- length(res)
#[1] 4 4 5 5 6 7 8 8 9
```